# Simulating the HP memristor in Python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, python, simulation

I am trying to simulate the non-linear electrical resistive device called memristor in python. The device is characterized by a change in conductivity as an electrical field is applied, and so the relationship between applied voltage and current through the device is hysteretic and non-linear. The system is described by the equations

\begin{equation}
    M(x) = R_\text{ON} \cdot x + R_\text{off} \cdot (1-x)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\mu_x \cdot R_\text{ON}}{D^2}\cdot i_\text{tran}(t)
\end{equation}
When a voltage is applied, the region where there is charge change in thickness, so x is used here as the internal state that describes how the region of charge changes in relation to the total thickness of the layer.
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{w}{D}, \hspace{10pt} 0 \le x \le 1 
\end{equation}
I have tried to set this up in Python, but lack of understanding of differential equations and little practical experience with simulating in Python makes it difficult to spot my mistakes. I am pretty sure I have some of the basics wrong. The code looks like this:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


R_ON = 100      #Resistance maximum conducting state [ohm]
R_off = 16e3    #Resistance minimum conducting state [ohm]
W = 2*np.pi     #Angular frequancy 
V_0 = 5         #Volts 
t0 = 0          #Time array start
tf = 1          #Time array stop
N = 50          #Array length
mu_V = 1e-14    #Oxygen vacancy mobility
D = 10e-9       #Titanium layer thickness
X0 = 0.76       #Normed charge region (initial value)



def M_tran(x):
    return R_ON*x+R_off*(1-x)

def i_tran(t, x):
    return (V_0*np.sin(W*t))/M_tran(x)

def odefun2(t, x):
    c = (mu_V*R_ON)/(D**2)
    return c*i_tran(t, x)




t = np.linspace(t0,tf,N+1)
T = odeint(odefun2, X0, t, tfirst=True)


U = np.multiply(i_tran(t, X0), M_tran(T[:,0]))

plt.plot(i_tran(t, X0), U)
```

Do I need a window function for x perhaps?

I'll attach the plot I get up if it can be of any help, although it makes no sense to me.
[Plot generated by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPAxI.png)

Comment: You're plotting U against i, does that make any sense in context?

Comment: I want to plot the current through the object as a function of applied voltage U.  Maybe I should instead set U equal to sin x and not calculate U through ohms law using the current i and the resistance (memristance) M.

Comment: I don't really know much about nonlinear electronics, but in linear electronics it usually makes more sense to think of the applied voltage as the given thing and the current comes from the voltage in combination with the properties of the device.

Comment: Also, you say $0 \leq x \leq 1$, but $x$ is actually a dynamic variable, so you should really check whether that assumption is maintained all the time.

Comment: Yes I agree. At this point, I am most concerned with what is returned from the ODE solver in Python. I apply a sinusoidal wave, but I get a perfect sinusoidal function back, so somewhere I am doing something wrong. I am struggling with the three functions and if I am using the arguments in the right way.

Comment: I think I need to implement a window function so the x stays within its boundaries. But at the moment it doesnt seem like much is happening anyways.

So basically what I am wondering about is if the arguments for the three functions are correct and if I am calling the different functions and using them together with the ODE solver in a correct way.

Comment: The basic structure looks fine. That being said, have you noticed that this equation is actually separable, so you can just integrate it analytically? It looks like you get something like $p(x)=\cos(2 \pi t)$ where $p$ is a quadratic function...

Comment: Yes I saw an attempt to do that in the article I read, so maybe that is a better solution. In more detail, I was unsure about the use of the initial value X0. As you can see I use that value multiple places, which seems odd. Maybe Im confusing the initial value X0 with the variable x somewhere.. Are you able to make sense of small details like that or are you saying it looks fine in a broader sense? I appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: Oh yeah, your call to i_tran in the plot call makes no sense. You are plotting the current at each time as if $x$ were the value it started at. That should probably be what you called $T$ (which is to say the values of $x$ obtained by the integrator).

Comment: Note that you'll need to be careful to define i_tran to do the division componentwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, the analytic solution to this question is as follows. Your ODE can be written as

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{f(t)}{x+b(1-x)}$$

where $f(t)$ is a given forcing (which has constants as well as the actual input voltage in it); note that I have absorbed your $R_{on}$ into $f$ as well. This equation can be solved as

$$\int_{x_0}^x y+b(1-y) dy = \int_0^t f(s) ds.$$

Thus

$$\frac{(1-b)x(t)^2}{2} + b x(t) - \left ( \frac{(1-b) x_0^2}{2} + bx_0 \right ) = \int_0^t f(s) ds.$$

This is just a quadratic equation that you can solve for $x(t)$ for each $t$; the coefficients are actually structured such that a solution is guaranteed to exist at least for a short time no matter what $b$ or $x_0$ is, which I find quite neat.

Numerically it looks like the only real problem with your implementation is that in the call to i_tran inside the plotter, you need to use the time-dependent values of $x$ not the initial value.

Comment: Thank you for great help! :-)  got it to work now! The analytic solution is definitely very interesting too, I'll try to plot in and compare.